# How can I clone a branch with the same folder name as the branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, cloning

I tried to clone different branches in the same location but it kept creating folders having the name of the `master(main)` and not the specific `branch`.

The command I used:
`git clone --branch <branch-name> <git-URL>/sampleproject.git`

The folder name on my local drive is `sampleproject`. How can I clone a branch with the folder name `<branch-name>`?

Comment: add <branch-name> at the end of your clone command

Comment: What do you mean by "clone a folder"? Git isnt SVN and branches aren't "folders". In git, think of a branch as a _parallel universe_ with its own timeline that may or  may not converge with another branch/universe/timeline.

Comment: Why not just do a normal clone and then `checkout` in a subsequent command?

Comment: `git clone`'s `<directory>` parameter is the last command-line argument, so `git clone --branch sampleproject <git-URL>/sampleproject.git sampleproject` should do it.

Comment: The folder name has nothing to with what branch you checkout as you clone.

Comment: Note you are not cloning a branch. You are downloading a complete clone and then checking out a particular branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried to clone different branches in the same location

I don't think you should be doing that because it *introduces too many moving parts* into your environment. Why not clone the repo *normally* and then `git checkout` the branch you want?

e.g.

```
cd ~/repos

# Clone the repo into the directory `~/repos/sampleproject` (which will default to checking out the 'master' or 'main' branch):
git clone <git-URL>/sampleproject.git sampleproject

# Get into the repo:
cd sampleproject

# Checkout the branch 'sampleproject'
git checkout -b sampleproject
```

More succintly, the `git clone` command *does* let you do this in a single line:

```
git clone --branch sampleproject <git-URL>/sampleproject.git sampleproject
```

Note that the name `sampleproject` is repeated 3 times because:

- `--branch sampleproject` is the branch that will be `checkout`'d.
- `sampleproject.git` is the remote repo that will be cloned.
- `sampleproject` (at the end) is the name of the directory in your local filesystem that the repo will be cloned into.

But this is a bad idea: **don't confuse yourself by using the same name for different things.** If this were my repo I'd rename the `sampleproject` branch to something more descriptive.

---

But rather than cloning it from a remote repo every time, [why not use git's support for concurrent working-trees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)?

```
cd ~/repos

# Clone the repo into the directory `~/repos/sampleproject-master` (which will default to checking out the 'master' or 'main' branch):
git clone <git-URL>/sampleproject.git sampleproject-master

# Checkout the `branch1` branch to the directory `~/repos/sampleproject-branch1`
git worktree add --checkout -b branch1 sampleproject-branch1

# Checkout the `branch2` branch to the directory `~/repos/sampleproject-branch2`
git worktree add --checkout -b branch2 sampleproject-branch2
```

Comment: You forgot to cd into the repo?

Comment: @matt Where? In my first example the `cd` is the 3rd command doen. In my other sample for `worktree` you **don't** want to `cd` into the repo directory. Worktrees should be kept separate.